# I have 6 plots in a for loop but I am struggling to use plt.subplots to put them into a 2x3 format

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have 6 plots in a for loop, but instead of the output graphs showing vertically, it would be nice for them to be in a 2x3 view.

This is my for loop for the plots:

```
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i,l,k in zip(basin_id,basin_id_lsds,basin_names):
    plt.plot(time_months,remove_seasonality(climatology(ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),label=k)
    plt.title(k)
    plt.ylim(-30,50)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('FWF Anomalies')
    plt.show()
```

I first tried this to change the subplots, making nrows = 3, ncols=2:

```
for i,l,k in zip(basin_id,basin_id_lsds,basin_names):
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
ax.plot(time_months,remove_seasonality(climatology(ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),label=k)
ax.set_title(k)
#plt.ylim(-30,50)
#plt.grid()
#plt.xlabel('Time')
#plt.ylabel('FWF Anomalies')

plt.show()
```

but i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-f21ee20e457f> in <module>
      1 for i,l,k in zip(basin_id,basin_id_lsds,basin_names):
      2     fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
----> 3     ax.plot(time_months,remove_seasonality(climatology(ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,i,l)),label=k)
      4     ax.set_title(k)
      5     #plt.ylim(-30,50)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

How do I fix this problem to get the 2x3 view of the plots?

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)`

Comment: What does basin_id have?

Comment: basin_id is just this array for the input data

Comment: I updated the question to try and make it clearer. I used fig,ax plt.subplots

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)` should be outside the loop.

Comment: I still get the error with saying with ax.plot "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'"

Comment: `for i,l,k,ax in zip(basin_id,basin_id_lsds,basin_names,ax.ravel())`

Comment: one last question.. in order to change the figure size of each plot and make it bigger, I tried plt.figure(figsize=(30,30)) outside the for loop but there was no chance in the fig size. how do I make the figure sizes larger?

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

- Create the subplots outside the loop:
- Loop over the subplots using `axs.ravel()`.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))

for i,l,k,ax in zip(basin_id,basin_id_lsds,basin_names, axs.ravel()):
    ax.plot(...)
```